# Optional code in a template class

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Assume that we have that `struct X;` and we use C++11 compiler (e.g. gcc 4.7). I'd like to emit some code and attributes if and only if, say, `opt = true`.

```
template <bool opt>
struct X {
  void foo() {
    EMIT_CODE_IF(opt) {
      // optional code
    }

    // ...common code...
  }

  int optional_variable; // Emitted if and only if opt is true
};
```

1. As for the code, I assume that normal `if` suffices.
2. But as for the attributes, if one leaves them unused (when `opt = false`), will and **COULD** they be automatically omitted by the compiler? I definitely do not want them there when `opt = false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to avoid attributes in a class template is to derive from a base class template which is specialized to be empty if the member shouldn't be there. For example:

```
template <bool Present, typename T>
struct attribute {
    attribute(T const& init): attribute_(init) {}
    T attribute_;
};
template <typename T>
struct attribute<false, T> {
};

template <bool opt>
class X: attribute<opt, int> {
    ...
};
```

With respect to optional code you may get away with a conditional statement but often the code wouldn't compile. In this case, you'd factor out the code into a suitable function object which be specialized to do nothing when not needed.

Comment: Well, thank you. But honestly, if that is the **right** solution, we must admit that there's still something wrong in the C++ design. Because... using a macro, one can achieve that with the minimal effort. But that's the C style, of course.

Comment: I mean, I see no way how to avoid the code duplication or the "functor bloat".

Comment: Why is that? Things work reasonably easy with a lot of expressiveness, allowing structural customizations not available in many languages addressing a similar domains. That said, there were several proposals on "static if" in some form or another which want to deal with a nicer syntax. I'm not, yet, convinced that these proposals indeed make it better.

Comment: `static_if`... I was looking for something like that for 20 minutes on Google. But it didn't manage to get into C++11, right? It would be definitely a help. ...I would say, if we have to use inheritance or a functor to achieve this in C++, there's definitely a big room for improvement :-)

Comment: However it is spelled, it isn't in C++ 2011. It may get into C++ 2014 but even this isn't entirely clear. There were several proposals discussed, e.g., [this one](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3322.pdf) by Walter Brown.

Comment: Imagine this: You have an `addItem` class member function in a container which can be made thread safe with the template argument `safe == true`. When `safe == true` you want to store a mutex in the class and, moreover, add `mutex.lock()` at the 1st line of `addItem` and `mutex.unlock()` at the end. How simple would that be with `static_if`. Could you do that without inheritance and functors? Am I missing something?

Comment: ...in `C` it's trivial using classic `#ifdef ... #endif`.

Comment: If it is acceptable that a byte, possibly padded to a word, is spent in the case where no mutex is to be used: Sure, it can be done. Just create a class which is specialized to include a mutex or not without suitable members. Note, that in this particular case "static if" probably doesn't help your functions, though, because you want to use a guard object which would still be scoped inside the "static if"'s scope. Put differently: The use case you imagine doesn't benefit from "static if"! There are cases where "static if" would help but  it doesn't solve all problems.

Comment: The one byte/word overhead is the only reason to use inheritance (it takes advantage of the empty base optimization) and is likely a technique still used if "static if" were available. Just slopping in `mutex.lock()` and `mutex.unlock()` doesn't cut: it isn't exception safe and doesn't scale. Abstracting the problem and always using a lock guard, possibly without actually locking a mutex if none is required, is the proper approach.

Comment: I'd agree with the second part ("always using..."), yes, that's right. But any overhead is generally unacceptable. Finally, we don't use C++ exceptions at all, so that's not the problem :)

Comment: Exceptions isn't the only reason why not using a guard object doesn't scale. Intermediate returns and mismatched locks/unlocks are other unnecessary sources of errors. Also, just because you currently don't use exceptions means the code will never be used in an environment where exceptions are used. Personally, I don't subscribe to any excuses of not properly abstraction functionality and "static if" is making it more tempting to skip using the correct abstraction in this and other cases.

Comment: Well, no flame, but I would say, unfortunately, that many people in C++ committee only think they have the right sense for abstraction. People should learn from the elegance of languages like Haskell (even they're in a completely different functional setting). It's like in maths: "There's room only for elegant proofs." If simple tasks don't have simple solutions, one should get warned. There are coding standards (Google) not allowing C++ exceptions for the reason. It's not clear, if they're a good paradigm in critical apps.

Comment: @Martin you say it's trivial using `#ifdef` in C - you can use that in C++, too. However, factoring out the code that depends on `opt` into its own [policy](http://books.google.de/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&lpg=PR11&ots=YRfIYoVd91&dq=policy%20based%20design%20alexandrescu&lr&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=policy%20based%20design%20alexandrescu&f=false) makes the whole thing more readable, i.e. maintainable. I'd say whether to use locksguards or manually locking/unlocking a mutex is a different story, as is the good old discussion whether exceptions are the Right Thing To Do.

Comment: @ArneMertz Thank you for the link. I'm definitely going to read that chapter.